# Using images for multiple resolutions

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way for using one set of images for all the resolutions. I have an application, and I want to port it on all the android resolutions but I don't want to store 3 sets of images, for every resolution category. What would be the best practice to use as less images as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: It all depends. If you are making a game you can set the scaling and entire game screen would stretch. But it will be either blocky or blurry depending on the filter type. I suggest you make images for multiple resolutions after all. If you're unsure which resolutions to use, take a look at this guide: http://bigosaur.com/blog/31-android-resolutions-definite-answer

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can provide only one set of images, in the base `drawable` directory, and Android will automatically resize as required.

This may result in aliasing and images that are not as clear as would be possible if you were to provide images sized properly.

Comment: Do you know how this is working with Phonegap? I have got a folder structere like assets/www/images etc. At the moment images are 100px X 100 px and for instance in nexus 7 they are too small.

Comment: Auto resizing is only for res/, not assets/, in regular android apps; it seems the same is true for phonegap...

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean density, not resolution (in Android, applications do not work directly with resolution).

Actually, you don't need to support all 3 densities. Quote from developer.android.com:

*This pre-scaling mechanism works independently of the source. For instance, an application targeted for a high-density screen may have bitmaps only in the res/drawable-hdpi/ directory. If one of the bitmaps is a 240x240 icon and is loaded on a medium-density screen, the resulting bitmap will measure 160x160.*

I've done simple test: removed ldpi and mdpi density images, launched my app on mdpi skin and it scaled hdpi images nicely. It's not the best practice, but android's prescaling does its part as described.

Please read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

Comment: Suppose I need to fill in my fullscreen app background with an image. I have distinct images for all possible resolutions (240x320...480x854). How can I consider density in this case? large, normal, and small qualifiers are not enough either, because 240x400 and 240x432 are both considered normal.
 To the moment I think of loading corresponding backround for current resolution manually.

Comment: That may be worth separate question :). Its a little bit unclear why you need different backgrounds for 240x400 and 240x432. If you would put 240x432 image in drawable-ldpi (and put it as fill_parent background for your root View), it would scale it to 240x400 automatically. But if different backgrounds really needed - I'm not aware of declarative way of doing that. And I think Android's API designers wrapped resolution (to size and density) for the reason.

Comment: I understand that I must put specific images in all 3 density folders in order to have an application that looks good on all densities. It would be better to put all the images in one folder, and at run time to be scaled proportional to the baseline configuration, but to have the same aspect ratio. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool which makes this all a lot easier to manage. Although the images are stored in separate directories - the tool shows all resolutions together, and lets you auto-scale from one to another.

[image: Main screen]

you can get it here: http://hobbyistsoftware.com/AndroidImageViewer